# Magento api Your authorization request is invalid

Tags: magento

I'm trying to connect with Magento 1.X Rest Api, but when I try to do a get request on:

http://magentohsot.com.br/admin/oauth_authorize?oauth_token=XXXXXX

I get the error: An error occurred. Your authorization request is invalid.

I already checked the oauth consumer key and oauth consumer secret and they are right.
To generate the oauth_token I did a get request in Postman with this:

http://magentohost/oauth/initiate?oauth_consumer_key=xxxx&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1475102900&oauth_nonce=5wq5DG&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=nWhmHcih/DvtXuDOjjvJJVnWrss=&oauth_callback=xxxx

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please provide some code - impossible to help otherwise

Comment: There is no code, it's just a get request with postman to the cited url. I can show some specific code that you ask. But I coded nothing to do this.

Comment: @RobbieAverill I edited the question with some more details.

Comment: hey I got same issue because, I have logged in with admin user in another tab. So logged out from admin panel and try again.